# React native elements theme provider not working in testflight, but works in production mode in expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-elements, themeprovider

I have a few themes throughout my app that I use for buttons, and in development and production mode on expo, all of the buttons look fine. However, when installing the app as a tester from Testflight, all of the custom themed buttons look like default buttons. Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

[image: TestFlight image 1]
[image: TestFlight image 2]
[image: Expo production image 1]
[image: Expo production image 2]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Without seeing any code, it's going to be very difficult to help.  Check [mcve] for how to post your code.